# Are there any Ruby on Rails gems/jQuery plugins/tutorials that might help me implement this help system?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm building a web-app with quite a few complex features, and I'm trying to implement a way to help users as they learn to use it.

I'm thinking about having helper messages attached to certain html elements, which describe their function. These would appear by default. When a user clicks on a message, it would disappear and never be shown again.

I will need a helper_message model in the database to store the data, with a user having many helper_messages. Then when a helper message is clicked on the page, use ajax to set the removed field on the helper_message to true. On page load, only load the helper messages that haven't been 'removed'.

As this seems like it might be a somewhat common system to implement, are there any Ruby on Rails gems/jQuery plugins/tutorials that cover similar ground to this?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3):

Cool idea and i must say i've played with the thoughts of using little tooltips to explain certain elements on some of my webapps to but never got to it. So i did some research when i had the idea and i found this niftly little Jquery script called [Website tour](http://www.tympanus.net/Development/WebsiteTour/). And for nice and clear / styleable flash[:notice] / flash[:error] messages i created a ruby on rails plugin with a colleage based on the [gritter script](http://boedesign.com/blog/2009/07/11/growl-for-jquery-gritter/). You can find it [here](https://github.com/RobinBrouwer/gritter). And here is a link to a nice scaleable  tooltip called [Poshy tip](http://vadikom.com/tools/poshy-tip-jquery-plugin-for-stylish-tooltips/). Id love to see you're webapp when you are done with it / you implemented the tour/tooltip elements!.

I hope these scripts can help you reach you're goal/inspired you.